# how to remove [ from string in java

Tags: java, string

i have arraylist containing string which contains below value:-

```
[CN=globalExport,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com

CN=All_Users,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com

CN=SupplyChain,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com]
```

i want to remove [ & ] from string, I have tried replaceAll, replace for it but it is not working.
Any suggestions

Comment: Show how did you try replace

Comment: String is immutable did you reassign it after replace?

Comment: @soorapadman: correctly said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String myText = "[CN=globalExport,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com   
    CN=All_Users,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com    
    CN=SupplyChain,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com]";

myText = myText.replaceAll("[","").replaceAll("]","");
```

then you can use `myText` variable which will have '[' and ']' removed.

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0
[ " exception occurs in "myText = myText.replaceAll("[","").replaceAll("]","");" line.

Comment: why are you using `replaceAll` as this is not replacing regex

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked,

Answer (score 3):

```
    String s = "[CN=globalExport,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com\n" +
            "CN=All_Users,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com\n" +
            "CN=SupplyChain,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com]";
    s = s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String text = "[CN=globalExport,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com "
                + "CN=All_Users,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com "
                + "CN=SupplyChain,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com]";
System.out.println("Original Text: "+text);
text = text.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
System.out.println("Modified Text: "+text);
```

Output :

> Original Text:
>   [CN=globalExport,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com
>   CN=All_Users,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com
>   CN=SupplyChain,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com]
>
> Modified Text:
>   CN=globalExport,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com
>   CN=All_Users,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com
>   CN=SupplyChain,OU=Groups,OU=Demo,DC=seri,DC=sailpointdemo,DC=com

You can also use -

```
text = text.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
```